# How to add margins in nvd3 graphs

Tags: svg, margins, nvd3.js, rect

I am using nvd3.js library and its horizontal graph http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBarHorizontal.html
I am trying to add some margins between the bars by the following css but is not working.
http://jsfiddle.net/petran/x7Cdz/1/

```
rect {
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-bottom: 5px;}
```

Is there another way to accomplish that ?

Comment: That won't work. SVG styles don't understand margin-top, and margin-bottom.  It doesn't look like the library supports padding between the bars out of the box.  If you wanted to add it you'd probably add it here: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/multiBarHorizontal.js#L160

Answer (score 8):

.margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})

http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav

Answer (score 0):

Customize your chart options as you need. You can add margin to the chart options as shown below.

```
 $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'multiBarHorizontalChart',
                height: 450,
                margin : {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 40,
                    left: 55
                },
                x: function(d){return d.label;},
                y: function(d){return d.value;},
                //yErr: function(d){ return [-Math.abs(d.value * Math.random() * 0.3), Math.abs(d.value * Math.random() * 0.3)] },
                showControls: true,
                showValues: true,
                duration: 500,
                xAxis: {
                    showMaxMin: false
                },
                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Values',
                    tickFormat: function(d){
                        return d3.format(',.2f')(d);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```